# scanf() is not taking more than 6 times in a for loop

Tags: c

It is really very unexpected, I have looked a lot of time where can be the problem but couldn't find it.

**Problem is:
Say I've given 7 integers to calculate their average, but it is taking first 6 numbers and calculating their average.
However I give any number more than 6, it will calculate only first 6's**

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int n,i,total = 0;
int numArr[n];
printf("How many numbers do you want to print? => ");
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&numArr[i]);
    total += numArr[i];
}
printf("--------------------------------\n");
printf("Average of this %d numbers: %d",n,total/n);

}
```

I'm not sure whether it is compiler problem or problem of my code.

Comment: `n` is uniniatialzied when used in `VLA` initialization..UB

Comment: When you define the array `numArr`, what is the value of `n`? The correct answer is *indeterminate* (and in practice will be seemingly random). Such definitions are *not* re-done retroactively.

Comment: Incidentally, you don't need to store the values in an array at all.

Comment: Initialise the `numArr` array after `scanf("%d",&n)`

Answer (score 1):

initialize `n` first and then declare `numArr[n]`

Modify your code as

```
int n,i,total = 0;
printf("How many numbers do you want to print? => ");
scanf("%d",&n);
int numArr[n];
```

then scan the array.